# Python difference between zip and elementwise subtraction

Tags: python, list, subtraction

I was creating a function to calculate the root mean square error (RMSE) between two lists ([MSE wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error)). For that, I need an element-wise subtraction of the lists. With the lists pred (predictions) and obs (observations), my first attempt was to use this:

```
se = [(p-0) for p in pred for o in obs]
```

but that resulted in a list of length n*n, with n the length of the original list. Eventually, I found out that

```
se = [(p-o) for p, o in zip(pred, obs)]
```

was the way to go, but now I'm curious why the first method doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, there's a typo in your first code: `(p-0)` should be `(p-o)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version uses a [nested comprehension:](http://blog.lerner.co.il/understanding-nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/) **Every** element in `pred` is paired with **every** element in `obs` (`length == n * m`).

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) on the other hand, does an element-wise pairing like a *zip* (`length == min(n, m)`).

Answer (score 3):

Well you can just print and see how it works:

```
a = [6,7,8,9]
b = [1,2,3,4]
print 'a = ',a
print 'b = ',b
print 'zipped = ', zip(a,b) #list(zip(a,b)) for Python3
print 'Unzipped = ', [(p,o) for p in a for o in b]
```

Output:

```
a =  [6, 7, 8, 9]
b =  [1, 2, 3, 4]
zipped =  [(6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4)]
Unzipped =  [(6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3), (9, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to the question about the difference between nested list comprehension and `zip` -- that's already covered in the other answers -- but rather an alternative to using `zip`:

You could also use [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). This way you can calculate directly on the lists, e.g. pairwise arithmetic operations, matrix manipulation, etc. This should also be a good bit faster.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pred = np.array([10, 12, 13, 11, 15])
>>> obs = np.array([11, 15, 10, 10, 12])
>>> pred - obs
array([-1, -3,  3,  1,  3])
>>> (pred - obs)**2
array([1, 9, 9, 1, 9])
>>> np.mean((pred - obs)**2)**.5
2.4083189157584592
```

Comment: I'm using this on 1D lists that are no larger than 100 values long, so I doubt I will really notice how much faster it is, but I'll definitely consider using np for my lists in the future.

Comment: @MatthijsKramer Even if performance is not critical, you have to admit that `pred - obs` is much shorter and more readable than `[(p-o) for p, o in zip(pred, obs)]` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) in both cases:

```
se = [(p-0) for p in pred for o in obs]
```

Here you have used for loop inside for loop(Nesting)

But in your second try you used zip(list1,list2) which zips or pairs element-wise from both lists

Look the doc here for [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)